# Using Grunt html2js and concat, how do I reference a html file from the concat js file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-concat

I have a very large modularized AngularJS Application. I setup Grunt to create a single JS file from the multiple html files using html2js.

```
    html2js: {
        options: {
            base: 'dol',
            module: 'dol.templates',
            singleModule: true,
            useStrict: true,
            htmlmin: {
                collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
                collapseWhitespace: true,
                removeAttributeQuotes: true,
                removeComments: true,
                removeEmptyAttributes: true,
                removeRedundantAttributes: true,
                removeScriptTypeAttributes: true,
                removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true
            }
        },
        main: {
            src: ['app/modules/reporting/views/*.html'],
            dest: 'tmp/templates.js'
        }
    },
```

I then run concat on all of my js files and that newly created templates.js file:

```
    concat: {
        options: {
            separator: ';'
        },

        dist: {
            src: ['tmp/*.js', 'app/app.js', 'app/app.controller.js', 'app/common/directives/directives.js', 'app/app.factory.js', 'app/modules/reporting/controllers/reports.controller.js', 'app/modules/reporting/reports.routes.js', 'app/xenon.custom.js'],
            dest: 'dist/app.js'
        }
    },
```

I now have one file with all of my js files and html files: app.js

I am referencing that dist/app.js file in my index.html

The issue I am having is inside my application I reference some of the HTML files like such:

```
// Layout Related Directives
directive('reportsSummary', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: appHelper.templatePath('modules/reporting/views/reportssummary.view')
    };
}).
directive('reportsSidebarMenu', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: appHelper.templatePath('modules/reporting/views/reports.sidebar.menu')
    };
}).
directive('reportsFooter', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: appHelper.templatePath('modules/reporting/views/reports.footer')
    };
});
```

When I run my deployed application, I get an error stating that it cannot find those files. When I run my app locally, it runs fine because the files reside in the proper paths.

Question is: When deploying the app, how do I reference those html files in my code since they now reside in dist/app.js

I also reference the html files in my ui-router:
(function () {
    'use strict';

```
angular
    .module('dol')
    .config(reportsConfig);

reportsConfig.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider'];

function reportsConfig($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/reports');

    $stateProvider.state('reports',
        {
            url: '/reports',
            templateUrl: 'app/modules/reportspage/views/reports.view.html',
            controller: 'reportsController'
        });
}
```

})();

Comment: Have you tried https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-text-replace ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using ngtemplates in your grunt task:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-angular-templates

Comment: I do not want to cache the templates. Furthermore, if I combine them all into one .js file, how would my ui-router access that html file from inside the newly created app.js file?   My ui-router uses this relative path to find the html file:   templateUrl: 'app/modules/reportspage/views/reports.view.html'  Now that all my html is combined into one file in the dist/app.js file, how does my ui-router know to look in the dist/app.js file versus the specified relative path? When I run it locally, the html files all exist, but when I combine the html files on deployment, I use dist/app.js.

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to cache the templates? The template cache essentially says "if you are looking for `app/modules/reportspage/views/reports.view.html`, here it is" and returns the body of the html page.